# What phrase is omitted after "as advanced" in this context?

Tags: ellipsis

This is from [a news article](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/06/04/health/rectal-cancer-radiation-treatment.html) :

> As years went by, some researchers began to wonder if radiation was
> still necessary. Chemotherapy, surgery and medical imaging had
> improved, and patients were being diagnosed earlier, before their
> cancer was **as advanced**.

"**As**" seems to be an adverb meaning 'to the same degree or amount' in this context so I think 'as to require radiation' is omitted after "**as advanced**" in this context.

Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the diagnosis is later in the course of the disease the cancer has developed further - it is more advanced when diagnosed. Earlier diagnosis means the cancer is less advanced. You could add a clarifying phrase to make the end of the sentence "before their cancer was as advanced as in the past".

Comment: Thank you very much.